# Laravel: How to configure cache properly

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I want to use cache in my laraver 6.3 app. I followed the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/cache), but after all steps my records do not apply into cache.

My config/cache.php

```php
  'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'cache',
        ],

        'dynamodb' => [
            'driver' => 'dynamodb',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
            'table' => env('DYNAMODB_CACHE_TABLE', 'cache'),
            'endpoint' => env('DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],
```

creating cache table migration

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cache', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('key')->unique();
            $table->mediumText('value');
            $table->integer('expiration');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cache');
    }
```

When I use

```php
  public function cacheUserToken($userId){
       $token = uniqid(base64_encode(Str::random(60)));
       $experationTime = 60;
       Cache::put($userId, $token, $experationTime);
   }
```

I expect that such record will be in cache table, but it doesnt.

In tutorial says that i need to install the memcached driver, I googled how to do it, but got answer that it is already in laravel from box.

There absolutely no error occure, it just not working. What do I miss?

Comment: which cache driver you have set on the .env file

Comment: @DhavalPurohit in .env file I have CACHE_DRIVER=file

Comment: Then it will write the all the cache data into files. not in database.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit and what should I do?

Comment: change it to the database @aabdugaliyev